# How can I store a plugin method call in the settings of another plugin call without executing it in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, methods

I have two jquery plugins. Lets call them plugin A and plugin B. I want to assign a method from plugin B to one of the settings of plugin A. My problem is that the method from pluginA.settings.action is executed as soon as it's defined in the HTML.

```
<button>Click Me!</button>
<div id="message"></div>
$('button').pluginA({
  action: $('#message').pluginB("btnAction")
});
```

How can I do this without actually calling the method when it is defined in the settings of plugin A?

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.pluginA = function(method) {
        var $element;
        var methods = {
            init : function(options) {
                settings = $.extend({}, this.pluginA.defaults, options);
                return this.each(function() {
                    $element = $(this);
                    element = this;
                  $element.on('click', function(){
                    settings.action;
                  })
                })
            }
        }
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method "' +  method + '" does not exist in pluginA plugin!');
        }

    }

    $.fn.pluginA.defaults = {  
            ajaxUrl: "http://wordpress.com",
            eventId: 0,
            element: null
    }

    $.fn.pluginA.settings = {}

    $.fn.pluginB = function(method) {
        var $element;
        var methods = {
            init : function(options) {
                settings = $.extend({}, this.pluginB.defaults, options);
                return this.each(function() {
                    $element = $(this);
                    element = this;
                })
            },
            btnAction: function(){
                $element.text('The button was clicked!');
            }
        }
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method "' +  method + '" does not exist in pluginB plugin!');
        }

    }

    $.fn.pluginB.defaults = {  
            ajaxUrl: "http://wordpress.com",
            eventId: 0,
            element: null
    }

    $.fn.pluginB.settings = {}

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Make the value of the `action` property a function and set it to `action: function(){ return $('#message').pluginB("btnAction")}`.